# ng-content and tooglable text centered

Tags: angular, dataframe, alignment, center, angular2-ngcontent

i need my ng content and text to align to center
this is the current situation:

```
<div
    (mouseenter)="mouseEnter()"
    (mouseleave)="mouseLeave()"
    style="text-align: center"
>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

<span style="text-align: center" *ngIf="isTitleVisable">
    {{ title }}
</span>
<div *ngIf="!isTitleVisable"><br /></div>
```

[state 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQF6Y.png)

[state 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkZ28.png)

i want the ng content to stay in place exactly like the 2nd pic
but when the text mouse exit the ng-content,the text disapear (as it should) and the content goes  left.

Comment: please provide `mouseLeave()` and `mouseEnter()` functions too.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you use a variable -sorry if the response is not exact fit to your requirements-, So imagine some like

```
<div (mouseenter)="on=true"
     (mouseleave)="on=false"
     [style.text-align]="on?'center':null"
>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

When a mouse enter a variable defined in your .ts becomes true, when the mouse out the variable becomes false. The [style.text-align] is center when the variable is true and null (if is null, angular remove the `style.text-align` attribute) when is false.

You can use also use a class `center` in your .css and use some like

```
  [class.center]="on?true:null"
```

or

```
   [ngClass]="on?'center':null"
```